# SSIS Bulk Insert doesn´t work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, bulkinsert

I'm trying to execute a Bulk Insert task in a SSIS package in SQL Server, but it shows error trying to open the file or trying to find the file. Searching in the web the errors can be:

**The path is incorrect:** It is not this, I've tried with normal path and UNC path, if I copy the path in the explorer it opens the file.

**The BD User doesn't have permissions:** The user executing the task is my user who has admin privileges and the DB user is BulkAdmin and SysAdmin.

The error with UNC path is:

```
SSIS package "BulkInsert.dtsx" starting.
Error: 0xC002F304 at Bulk Insert Task, Bulk Insert Task: An error occurred with the following error message: "Could not bulk insert because file '\\MyMachine\D$\Pro\Pro Mig\Mig\Filess\XXXXXXX130309.TXT' could not be opened. Operating system error code 53(The network path was not found.).".
Task failed: Bulk Insert Task
SSIS package "BulkInsert.dtsx" finished: Success.
```

The error with normal path is:

```
SSIS package "BulkInsert.dtsx" starting.
Error: 0xC002F304 at Bulk Insert Task, Bulk Insert Task: An error occurred with the following error message: "Could not bulk insert because file 'D:\Pro\Pro Mig\Mig\Filess\XXXXXXX130309.TXT' could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).".
Task failed: Bulk Insert Task
SSIS package "BulkInsert.dtsx" finished: Success.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you running this in SQL Agent or interactively in BIDS? It sounds like you are running it remotely on a different server and expecting the path to be the same.

Comment: I tried two differents ways, in BIDS and with a bat file with dtexec

Comment: The BAT file with DTExec - did you run that locally or within SQL Agent? If we focus on running it in BIDS: that should definitely run it locally under your security context, which means if you can see that path, your SSIS package should be able to see it. What happens if you type Start / Run and type that path into the run box, does it find it?

Comment: I execute the bat locally, and if I copy the past into Run it opens the file, with the UNC path and the normal path.

Comment: Bizarre. All I can suggest is that you use procmon to monitor your process and ensure it is running as who you think it is, and doing the things you expect. It's a very handy tool.

Answer (score 3):

To use the SSIS 2008 Bulk Insert Task, the source file must reside on the same server as the target database.  If you attempt to use the Task when the source file is on a remote server, you will get those errors.